# Canvas toDataURL doesn't return whole URL on first try

Tags: javascript, html, image, canvas

I've got some code which takes a drawing made on in SVG with Raphael (a 400x400 image loaded into the SVG with Raphael), converts it to a canvas with canvg, and should then take canvas.toDataURL and make it an image. All of this should happen when a button is pushed. The first two steps work, but the third is glitchy. The first time I press the button, a 300x150 blank image is placed in the final div instead of the 400x400 image. If I press the button again, the image shows up fine (correct size and everything). I've tried to use both img.onload and the jquery version $(img).load but neither seems to keep the problem from happening. Therefore, I feel like it's an issue with the canvas having not been drawn completely yet but I can't prove that and I can't seem to make the code wait until it has been drawn. Below is all the code. I tried to make it a fiddle but I kept getting security errors with the image.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://canvg.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/rgbcolor.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://canvg.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/canvg.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/raphael.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/excanvas.compiled.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var nowX, nowY, R = Raphael("svg_drawing", 400, 400);

            $($("svg").get(0)).attr("xmlns:xlink", "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink");
            var templ = R.image("images/band_clutch.jpg", 0, 0, 400, 400);

        });

        function toImg(){
            var svg = $("#svg_drawing").html().replace(/>\s+/g, ">").replace(/\s+</g, "<");
            var canvas = $("#canvas")[0];
            canvg(canvas, svg);
            var imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpg');
            var img = new Image();
            $(img).load(function(){
                $("#drawing_area").html("");
                $(img).appendTo("#drawing_area");
            });
            img.src = imgData;
        }

    </script>
    <title>Sandbox</title>
</head>
<body style="margin: 0; width:3000px">
    <div id="svg_drawing" style="background-color:white;display:inline-block;height:400px;width:400px;border:1px solid black;"></div>

    <canvas id="canvas" style="display:inline-block;height:400px;width:400px;border:1px solid red;"></canvas>

    <div id="drawing_area" style="background-color:white;display:inline-block;height:400px;width:400px;border:1px solid black;"></div>
            <button onclick="toImg()" style="display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;">Do it</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like the canvas area is staying at the default 350 x 150. Try setting

```
canvas.width = canvas.height = 400;
```

before drawing (keep the inline CSS as-is).

To fix the actual rendering issue, you need to tell the canvg method to do the toDataURI stuff asyncronously, once the rendering has been complete:

```
function toImg(){
        var svg = $("#svg_drawing").html().replace(/>\s+/g, ">").replace(/\s+</g, "<");
        var canvas = $("#canvas")[0];
        canvg(canvas, svg, {
            renderCallback : function(){
                var imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpg');
                var img = new Image();
                $(img).load(function(){
                    $("#drawing_area").html("");
                    $(img).appendTo("#drawing_area");
                });
                img.src = imgData;
                }
            });           
     }
```

Comment: That only solves the issue of it being the wrong size and even that's not really an issue. The second time I run the code (without reloading the page) it's the correct size and it shows the picture. My problem is the first time it's run (when I want it to work correctly), it gives me a blank picture, not even a scaled copy of the SVG.

Comment: OK - have added the solution to the answer. Essentially you just need to wait for canvg to do the rendering before doing the rest.

Comment: That did it thank  you. I was so busy looking at examples of canvg that didn't have the callback that I didn't know it existed.